# Basis for a topology lemma

Tags: general-topology

I am confused by a lemma in my textbook. The lemma is the following:

Lemma: If $B$ is any basis for (topology) $\mathbb{T}$ then

- $T$ is the union of sets from $B$
- if $B_1,B_2\in B$ then $B_1\cap B_2$ is the union of sets from $B$

The definition of a basis for a topology in the textbook is:

Definition: A basis for a topology $\mathbb{T}$ on a set $T$ is a collection $B\subset \mathbb{T}$ such that every set in $\mathbb{T}$ is a union of sets from $B$.

The thing I don't understand is what does the second statement mean? What does "$B_1\cap B_2$ is the union of sets from $B$" exactly mean?  Also, why is it called a union when  it's an intersection?

Comment: It means that $B_1\cap B_2=\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$ for some index set $I$ and $B_i\in B$ for each $i\in I$.

Comment: @Zuy oh okay, i see now how this connects from the definition. So for example can $B_1$ be expressed in terms of the other sets?

Comment: It depends on the topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the lemma says that the set $B_1\cap B_2$ it is also union of some subsets of $\mathcal B$.

Other lemma that you can find in some texts is the following. It can help you to understand yours.

Let $X$ a non-empty set. $\mathcal B\subset \mathcal P (X)$ is basis of any topology on $X$ if and only if:

1. $X=\cup_{B\in \mathcal{B}}B$
2. $\forall B_1, B_2\in\mathcal B, \ \forall x\in B_1\cap B_2 \ \exists B_3 \mid x\in B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$.

Using the second part of this lemma you can easily prove yours.

Comment: thank you for the answer. So for example can $B_1$ be expressed in terms of the other sets?

Comment: @ДарияСоколова No, that's not an example of the lemma and might not be the case.

Comment: Well you can pick $B_2 = B_1$ in the lemma and express $B_1$ as a union of elements of the basis, but this is not very interesting since $B_1$ is an element of the basis and hence can always be expressed in terms of itself.

Comment: By my lemma, $\forall x\in B_1\cap B_2  \ \exists B_x \in \mathcal B \ \mid \ x\in B_x\subset B_1\cap B_2.$ So you can write $B_1\cap B_2=\cup_{x\in B_1\cap B_2} B_x$.

Comment: ДарияСоколова specifically said "in terms of *the other sets*". I don't think $B_1=B_1$ qualifies for that.

Answer (score 0):

The second condition according to wiki:

> Let$ B_1, B_2$ be base elements and let $I $be their intersection. Then for each$ x$ in $I$, there is a base element $B_3$ containing$ x$ such that $B_3$ is subset of $I$. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#:%7E:text=Not%20all%20families%20of%20subsets,must%20be%20equal%20to%20X.)

---

I think an example will help more than anything: Consider a set $O= \{ 1,2,3 \}$ then a topology which can be defined on the set is given as $X= \{ \phi, X, \{1\}, \{2,3\} \}$

Question: Does there exist a set $B$ such that taking the elements of $B$ and unioning them gives back $X$? Yes!  $B= \{ \phi,\{1 \} , \{2, 3 \} \}$ . Trivially we get the elements $\{1 \}$ and $\{2, 3 \}$ in X by considering elements of $B$  and the set $X$ itself can be constructed by taking union of $ \{1 \}$ and $\{2,3 \}$.

Analogy: Consider some lego structure, now we can decompose the lego structure as combination of some set of lego blocks. We also impose an extra property on this set of blocks that if we see the common part of two building block, there must be another building block which can make that.

Comment: I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaf9Cp_MV1s&list=PLrvK1zCpb85D96AGKDyszjsAdShtxpd_d&index=24) helpful.

Comment: oops I called both things X, fixed the error srry